# Launch Failed. Binary not found. Compile and run C++ in eclipse for Java SE?

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have looked at various questions and other websites regarding this. I'm not able to find and proper solution

I have downloaded Eclipse which came along with the Android Development Tools. I'm using the the same eclipse for running java programs. Now that i want to run C/C++ programs,
I downloaded and installed the CDT plugin for eclipse. 
Then I downloaded minGW, set the environment variable "Path" under system variables to the "bin" directory of minGW
But when I run the program, it gives and Error "Launch Failed. Binary not found."
Please help me resolve this issue
Thank you

Comment: Which binary is not found? The compiler? I guess you chose the MinGW toolchain when creating the project and you built your project before you tried to run it? Is this where the error happens, while building the project or did you try to run it directly without building? This would result in an error since it has to be built first, after that CDT recognizes changes and rebuildts automatically before the program is run.